# R boxplot how is this manual fill wrong

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, boxplot

I would like to colour my boxplot variables differently. I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8320462/ggplot2-how-to-adjust-fill-colour-in-a-boxplot-and-change-legend-text) and tried the following but the plot boxes are all the standard white colour (i have 6 factors in Type). What should i change?

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(PGcounts, aes(Type, Word)) + 
            geom_boxplot() + 
            coord_trans(y = "log10") +
            scale_fill_manual(values = c("white","white","white","red","blue","white"))
```

Comment: the -1 is unfortunate since the question is genuine and the background work is linked. Furthermore, the answer shows that it's not obvious why in one case you would list the manual colors through "scale_fill_manual" while in another you add them through geom_boxplot().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also you can just change from `geom_boxplot()` to `geom_boxplot(aes(fill=Type))` in you original codes.

ex:

```
ggplot(PGcounts, aes(Type, Word)) + 
        geom_boxplot(aes(fill=Type)) + 
        coord_trans(y = "log10") +
        scale_fill_manual(values = c("white","white","white","red","blue","white"))
```

Comment: thanks - tha's great to know and I tried it. However in this particular case i wanted specific colours.

Comment: Your original codes in the question should work for manual color filling (i.e., assigning specific colors) with this change. If you add `aes(fill=Type)` into `geom_boxplot()`, then `scale_fill_manual()` will work.

Comment: I appreciate that. I had not realized that I needed both in place for it to work - i thought it was one or the other.

Answer (score 3):

What has to change is

```
geom_boxplot() +
```

to

```
geom_boxplot(fill = c("white","white","white","red","blue","white")) +
```

and remove

```
scale_fill_manual(values = c("white","white","white","red","blue","white"))
```