# How do fill a boxplot with color?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to create four boxplots next to each other. They should all filled with another color. I tried: scale_fill_manual(values=c("1"="red", "2"="green", "3"="yellow", "4"="blue"))

```
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 
input <- "C:\\statistical_tests\\boxplot.csv" 
boxplot<- read.csv(input, sep=";") 

library(ggplot2) 
library(scales) 
means <- aggregate(number ~ CPOD, paper, mean) 
p <- ggplot(boxplot, aes(group=time,y=number, x=as.character(time))) +
     geom_boxplot()+ theme_bw() + 
     scale_fill_manual(values=c("1"="red", "2"="green", "3"="yellow", "4"="blue"))+ 
             panel.grid.minor=element_line(colour="white"), 
             axis.text.x = element_text(size=8, colour="black"),
             axis.text.y=element_text(size=8, colour="black")) 
print(p)
```

Unfortunately, it is not working.
Could someone help me?
Thank you very much!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8320462/ggplot2-how-to-adjust-fill-colour-in-a-boxplot-and-change-legend-text

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ggplot2: How to adjust fill colour in a boxplot (and change legend text)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8320462/ggplot2-how-to-adjust-fill-colour-in-a-boxplot-and-change-legend-text)

Answer (score 0):

Could this be what you want?

```
data("iris")
ggplot( iris, aes( x = Species, y = Sepal.Length, fill = Species ) ) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

Beware that this works only if the x-axis variable is either a factor or a character. You can define it in the `data.frame` or you can a more on-the-fly approach as shown below. This is useful when you don't want to change the structure of your original data.

```
data("iris")
ggplot( iris, aes( x = as.factor(Species), y = Sepal.Length, fill = Species ) ) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but it is not working. I have in one column "number" and in the other column time (from 1 to 4). Now I would like to create 4 boxplots: time on the x-axis and number on the y-axis. Each of the 4 boxplots should have another color. I tried: scale_fill_manual(values=c("1"="red", "2"="green", "3"="yellow", "4"="blue") and scale_fill_manual(values=c(red", "green", "yellow", "blue")

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want a single plot with 4 box plots in it, or do you want to have 4 independent plot?

Comment: I would like to create 4 boxplots in one figure (like the figure, which you have sent)

Comment: Then why my example does not work? All you want is to have a factor variable on x-axis and your outcome variable as y-axis. You then color each box plot by simply putting `fill = time` within `aes()`. Something like `ggplot(data, aes(x = time, y = number, fill = time) +geom_boxplot()`

Comment: It says: "Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale"

Comment: There you go. You want to convert `time` to factor. This trick doesn't work if you have a continuous variable (i.e. `numeric`). I will update my answer above to adjust for this.